# What are good default items to add to .hgignore when using Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, mercurial, eclipse-cdt, hgignore

I'm new to using Eclipse (CDT for C++ use) and would like any hints or pointers to a good default set of items to add to my ignore list (e.g. in MS Visual Studio I typically add `*.suo`, `*.ncb`, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

I always add:

```
.cproject
.project
```

which are eclipse generated files.